# Finding the lowest value for specific key in a deeply nested array

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

Given an array with the following structure:

```
$orders = [
     0 => [
              'volume' => 1926,
              'lowPrice' => 1000.00,
              'date' => 2016-12-29 00:45:23
     ],
     1 => [
              'volume' => 145,
              'lowPrice' => 1009.99,
              'date' => 2016-12-31 14:23:51
     ],
     2 => [
              'volume' => 19,
              'lowPrice' => 985.99,
              'date' => 2016-12-21 09:37:13
     ],
     3 => [
              'volume' => 2984,
              'lowPrice' => 749.99,
              'date' => 2017-01-01 19:37:22
     ],
     // ...
]
```

I'm looking for the most performant way to find the lowest value for `lowPrice`. The size of `$orders` will more than likely be larger than 500 items. For the given array, the result would be as follows:

```
$lowestPrice = $this->findLowestPrice($orders);

echo $lowestPrice; // 749.99
```

Comment: Do you want to find the lowest value once or multiple times over a slightly changing dataset? If only once: iterate (`O(n)`), if multiple times: keep some kind of data structure, for instance a min heap (`O(n log n)` for updating, `O(1)` for getting the minimum).

Comment: where is the dataset `$orders` coming from? database? json? xml?

Comment: @RolandStarke That is what I'm currently doing, but I feel like it is inefficient.

Comment: @cmorrissey dataset is from a json source.

Comment: @EricS. You will not notice a difference in performance. All solutions here take <1ms for 500 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract an array of `lowPrice` and find the `min()`:

```
echo min(array_column($orders, 'lowPrice'));
```

Since those appear to be floats, you'll probably want [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) or [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the value of the lowest price (not the index in the array or something) you can use [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/array_reduce):

```
$orders = [
     0 => [
              'volume' => 1926,
              'lowPrice' => 1000.00,
              'date' => "2016-12-29 00:45:23"
     ],
     1 => [
              'volume' => 145,
              'lowPrice' => 1009.99,
              'date' => "2016-12-31 14:23:51"
     ],
     2 => [
              'volume' => 19,
              'lowPrice' => 985.99,
              'date' => "2016-12-21 09:37:13"
     ],
     3 => [
              'volume' => 2984,
              'lowPrice' => 749.99,
              'date' => "2017-01-01 19:37:22"
     ],
];

$lowestPrice = array_reduce(
    $orders,
    function($c, $v)
    {
        if ($c === null)
            return $v["lowPrice"];

        return $v["lowPrice"] < $c ? $v["lowPrice"] : $c;
    }
);
```